# assign values to variable names in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, variables

Is there a way to assign values to variable names which are both supplied by the user?

I thought of something along these lines:

```
function varargout=my_fun(varargin)

for i=1:2:nargin
eval('varargin{i}=varargin{i+1}')
end

>> my_fun('a',1,'b',2)

>> a

1

>> b

2
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using `assignin`, but I strongly recommend not to use such solution. It violates the common expectations of a variable scope. Besides this, `assignin` and `eval` are two of the best option to confuse the matlab editor, which results in many useless recommendations and warnings.

If you really need such a solution:

`assignin('caller',varargin{i},varargin{i+1})` to assign to the caller work space.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works great! I'll be careful in using it though :)